# Problem in installation of linux mint cinnamon on my 32 bits pc using Oracle virtual box

Tags: linux, linux-mint

As advised by my friends, I decided to learn linux OS with MINT cinnamon. Today I downloaded the mirror file from original website. I allocated 2048 MB ram and 200 GB space from virtual box. When I started virtual box and selected iso image it looked like this
[image]

Then I selected 'Start Linux Mint' option.
After a couple of minutes screen looked like this
[image]

After another couple of minutes virtual box screen turned black like this
[image]

I thought it may take some time. But nothing is happening further. Can anyone help?

Video card details given below[image]

Comment: I don't have virtualbox to hand to find the menu option but in the past I've had problems with Video RAM being too low.  Check your VM settings and see if you can allocate 100MB video ram or more.

Comment: But when I installed kali in same it worked perfectly. Though it was very bad experience for a newbie like me

Comment: While Kali and Mint are ultimately forked from the same version, they have wildly different settings out of the box so do check the video RAM.  Debugging a black screen is next to impossible.  Other terminals may still show up if you try:  ctrl-alt-[f1-f6]  This might get you to something that can at least begin to diagnose.

Comment: Yes, Kali is absolutely not for newbies, good call! However, since as you say, Mint _is_ for newbies, it will also likely be heavier on the graphics. Adding some more video ram could help as Philip suggested. If that doesn't help, please [edit] your question and tell us what graphics card you have.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Ubuntu 19.04 stuck on boot](//askubuntu.com/q/1136264)

Comment: I have edited the question with graphics card

Comment: Is your VirtualBox graphics adapter set to `VMSVGA`?

Comment: Yes 3d acceleration is enabled